# Cannot convert undefined or null to object : Next.js || React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, next.js

Currently receiving a error stating `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

The data the app is looking for comes from initial props.
I assume on the initial check no data is present, so it throws that error.

Would this be solved with an `async/await` ?

The initial posts_mentions is defaulted as an empty object

Here is the error image:
[image]

Here is the current code snippet

```
const { posts_mentions: postsMentions } = useData();
    const data = Object.keys(postsMentions).map(label => {
        return {
            name: shortName(label),
            posts: postsMentions[label].posts,
            mentions: postsMentions[label].mentions
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function something(){
const { posts_mentions: postsMentions } = await useData();
 const data = Object.keys(postsMentions).map(label => {
    return {
        name: shortName(label),
        posts: postsMentions[label].posts,
        mentions: postsMentions[label].mentions
    }
})
```

}

Comment: If this doesnt work than you need to share your code for useData function. But other than that when you console.log(posts_mentions) it shows you something right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try adding await before useData(). And if this is all part of bigger function than mark it as async. How does the useData() look? Is something async in it?

Comment: the initial data is being pulled in with `async` call when the app is loaded. can you provide an example of how `useData()` would look with async ?